# How to render a block in JSF, similar to Tapestry <delegate to="xxx"> tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to convert a Tapestry application to JSF.
Tapestry has a useful feature, block.
You can have many blocks (typically html snippets) on a page,
and then, using the `<delegate to="block">` component, choose one block
and render it dynamically at runtime.

Here is the Tapestry block documentation:
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Delegate.html

The closest thing I could find is `<ui:include src="#{sampleBean.block}"/>`
where sampleBean.getBlock() returns something like "/templates/block1.xhtml"
at runtime.

This solution forces me to have many small block files, which I don't think is efficient
or the best way to go.

Does nyone have a better solution?  Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to reuse the block multiple times on my page.
c:choose will let me choose the block once, but I want to have
the block reused multiple times on the page
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this `<ui:include>`ing template that contains series of blocks, and using a parameter, only one would be rendered at a time